# Rails arithmetic operation Error: undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two tables: `User`, `table1` and `table2`. `User has_many table1`. `User has_many table2`. `table2` has 3 columns: `column1`, `column2`, `column3`. What I want to do is to multiply the value in `column1` and `column2` by a number and save it to `column3`.

In my `table2.rb` class file, I have defined this method:

```
def calculate(tablerow)
  tablerow.column3 = (tablerow.column1 * 1) + (tablerow.column2 * 2) 
end
```

I have a method in `table1Controller`, which has a method do something. This method then calls the `table2#calculate` method above and passes an appropriate parameter.

When I call the `calculate` method, I get the following error message:

```
NoMethodError in table1Controller#dosomething
undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass
```

Now I know there is something not right about the `calculate` method. But I am not sure how to achieve what I am trying to achieve, which is just to do a calculation on the value of 2 columns and save the sum to a third column. My app uses SQLite3.

Comment: Why is everything times `column3` if you're trying to do the math on columns 1 and 2 and save it to 3?

Comment: You're right. Had a typo. Sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`undefined method * for nil:NilClass` means that one of the values you are trying to multiply is empty. In your example `tablerow.column3` is probably nil. I think you either have a typo in your code or gave the example code wrong because the code does not match what you say you are trying to achieve.

Give this a shot, it should also eliminate the need to call this action from your controller and just save the value of column3 each time you save or create a record in table2

```
class Table2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :calculate_column3

  def calculate_column3
   self.column3 = (self.column1 * 1) + (self.column2 * 2) 
  end
end
```

Comment: Oops. Yup did have a typo in the code. Will try the code you gave in the mOrning. Thanks for replying though. Appreciate it. :)